# How to upgrade Google Cloud Datalab?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

My Google Cloud Datalab instance kept being turned off after some operations, and looking at the stats it seems often times CPU usage reaches 100%.

How do I upgrade my VM instance to increase processing power?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance#changing_a_machine_type

"Console" method doesn't seem to work, use "gcloud" method instead:

> To change a machine type in gcloud, run the following command, replacing INSTANCE with the instance name, and MACHINE-TYPE with the desired machine type:
>
> gcloud compute instances set-machine-type INSTANCE --machine-type MACHINE-TYPE
>   Your machine type can be a predefined machine type, such as n1-standard-1, or a custom machine type. For example, a custom machine type with 4 vCPUs and 1 GB of memory can be specified as:
>
> --machine-type custom-4-1024

Comment: There is also a working example at the following link https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/wiki/Getting-Started